# Here batch geocoding API stopped working - HTTP Error 500

Tags: here-api, geocode

I've been using Here batch geocoding API through a Python script for weeks and it was working fine, but today it just stopped working. I checked my API key and it is enabled. I'm at 40% of the usage limit.

I tried sending the same CSV file three times to batch geocode, as I normally do, but none of them worked. It generated 3 jobs with the following IDs.

WWvUbZelaOdQuo0jKLcJEZjA2Ag6lAnx
99iwcLxJy4k41AhX3QLxvIRpi5OvySof
r3UVMv785j9b5DzYSK6nVIBCFT3RppFA

I am using the URL below to get the results, but it gives me an HTTP 500 error

[https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/WWvUbZelaOdQuo0jKLcJEZjA2Ag6lAnx/result?apiKey={}](https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/WWvUbZelaOdQuo0jKLcJEZjA2Ag6lAnx/result?apiKey=%7B%7D)

Obs: removed my api key from the URL to post this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is giving expected results :"

```
eecId,SeqNumber,seqLength,displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country



1,1,1,-23.60062,-46.63969,"Rua Mirassol, 133, Vila Clementino, São Paulo - SP, 04044-010, Brasil",133,Rua Mirassol,Vila Clementino,São Paulo,04044-010,,SP,BRA
```

Request
[https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/WWvUbZelaOdQuo0jKLcJEZjA2Ag6lAnx/result?apiKey={}](https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/WWvUbZelaOdQuo0jKLcJEZjA2Ag6lAnx/result?apiKey=%7B%7D)

Comment: tks, guess it was a transient issue